# How to print a single line of an existing file within a nested for loop in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop, cut

Probably this is a basic and simple question, but I have been looking around for two days and I am not able to figure out the way of solving it.

Given the following two pieces of working code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# First, I need to generate all even numbers for a list of n integers, in this example n=12

for number in 258 256 233 230 212 245 210 229 340 345 110 125; do
    for ((counter = 2; counter <= ${number}; counter += 2)); do
        printf "$counter\t" >> Even_numbers.txt
    done
    printf "\n" >> Even_numbers.txt
done


# Then, I need to print each of these lines into a different file with a specific directory structure, 
# that looks like the following one:

for i in 01 02 03; do
    mkdir "${i}"
    for j in panel1 panel2 panel3 panel4; do
        {
        mkdir "${i}/${j}"
        for dir in ${i}/${j}; do
            printf "# TEXT AAAAA\n" > "${i}/${j}/File_${i}_${j}.par"
            printf "# TEXT BBBBB\n" >> "${i}/${j}/File_${i}_${j}.par"
            # I need to print here a single line of the "Even_numbers.txt" file
            # for each of the File_${i}_${j}.par files
            # The 12 lines in the Even_numbers.txt file and the 12 .par files
            # are in the same order.
            printf "# TEXT CCCCC\n" >> "${i}/${j}/File_${i}_${j}.par"
        done
        }
    done
done
```

I need to print a single line of the "Even_numbers.txt" file in each of the files that are generated in the second chunk of code. The problem is that no matter what I do, I get always the entire file content written to each output, instead of the line that I need. The "Even_numbers.txt" file has the same number of lines and these lines are sorted in the same order as the files that are generated afterwards in each subdirectory.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What's the point of `for dir in ${i}/${j}`? You're only looping over one directory.

Comment: You don't need to put the body of `do` inside `{}`

Comment: In general, it's bad form to put `>>outfile` at the end of an individual `echo` or `printf`. Better to do the redirection at an outer scope so the file isn't being opened and closed over and over. For example, you could just put `>even_numbers.txt` after the first `done` in the file to redirect stdout for the whole `for` loop, and you wouldn't need the `>>even_numbers.txt`s at all.

Comment: `even_numbers.txt` only has one line in it. You separated the numbers by TAB, not newlines.

Comment: Also, it would be more efficient to _only_ `mkdir -p "$i/$j"` and not have any separate `mkdir "$i"` command. Remember that running external commands involves a substantial performance penalty (compared to builtins) -- you're doing a `fork()`, an `execve()`, and then linking/loading/etc.

Comment: first: I don't see any reference to `Even_numbers.txt` in the triple/nested`for` loop so I don't see how you "get always the entire file content written to each output"; second: you haven't told us how you determine which line from `Even_numbers.txt` goes into which output file; it would probably help if you cut this example down to a few files and then showed us the actual/desired output ... contents of `Even_numbers.txt` ... the contents of some *par files, eg, all of the `i=01` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can create all the directories at once:

```
mkdir -p {01..03}/panel{1..4}
```

To put one line in each file, redirect the loop input from `Even_numbers.txt`, and use `read` inside the loop to get one line at a time.

```
for i in 01 02 03; do
    for j in panel1 panel2 panel3 panel4; do
        parfile="${i}/${j}/File_${i}_${j}.par"
        read number
        printf "# TEXT AAAAA\n# TEXT BBBBB\n%s\n# TEXT CCCCC\n" "$number" > "$parfile"
    done
done < Even_numbers.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Barmar. The point of generating the directories and subdirectories in two steps is that I am running the code in MacOS and the names were stored in two variables and MacOS does not handle very well both variables in a single step even if you specify ``mkdir -p ${var1}/${var2}``. I have rewritten the code according to the example substituting both variables with hard coded names and including the read command inside the loop and now it works fine. Thanks again!!